# Is there a way to compile and execute dynamically generated code in C?

Tags: c

Is it possible to execute C code in a C program? For instance when reading input from the user.

Comment: It is possible, but it's not trivial.

Comment: Yes, operating systems do this all the time. They even let users, even unprivileged users, compile C code and run it on the fly, without reloading the operating system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built in to do this.

This simplest thing to do is save the given code to a separate file, invoke GCC as a separate process to compile the code, then run the compiled code in a new process.

Comment: Yes, and if you do that, you deserve to reap the consequences of any misbehavior of the dynamically-generated binary.

Answer (score 2):

Relatively easy: write C code to temporary file, invoke `cc` on temporary file to create shared library, use `dlopen` to load in and call functions in shared library

Harder: write C code to temporary file, invoke `cc` on temporary file to create conventional `.o` file, write your own dynamic linker to to load in and call functions in `.o` file

Harder: write a C interpreter to interpret C code directly

Answer (score 1):

If you're targetting x86/ARM and Unix/Linux, you might find libtcc of use:

```
#include <libtcc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void) {
    TCCState *s = tcc_new();
    tcc_set_output_type(s, TCC_OUTPUT_MEMORY);

    if (tcc_compile_string(s,
                           "#include <stdio.h>\n"
                           "void hello(void) {\n"
                           "    printf(\"Hello world\\n\");\n"
                           "}\n"
        ) != 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to compile the code\n");
        exit(2);
    }

    tcc_relocate(s, TCC_RELOCATE_AUTO);

    void (*hello)(void) = tcc_get_symbol(s, "hello");
    hello();
}
```